# In what format is ActiveJob :at key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, rails-activejob

I am trying to understand in what format `:at` for `ActiveJob` is, so I can use `assert_enqueued_with` with `:at` parameter.

Currently I've got this test which passes:

```
tomorrow = 1.day.from_now.to_date
assert_enqueued_with(job: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob) do
  onboarding.start_onboarding
  job_date = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs[0][:at]
  assert_equal tomorrow, Time.at(job_date).to_date
end
```

But then I've realised that `assert_enqueued_with` has `:at` parameter and I would prefer to use it instead of last two lines in the block. Problem is, `tomorrow` variable seems to be in a different format than `:at`, which makes this fail:

```
tomorrow = 1.day.from_now.to_date
assert_enqueued_with(job: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob, at: tomorrow) do
  onboarding.start_onboarding
end
```

with this error:

```
Minitest::Assertion: No enqueued job found with {:job=>ActionMailer::DeliveryJob, :at=>Wed, 31 May 2017 13:12:05 UTC +00:00}
```

As you can see, `tomorrow` is a date, say `Wed, 31 May 2017`, while `job_date` is some kind of a large number, say `1496236366.183789`. Hence I am trying to convert `tomorrow` into the same format.

Would really appreciate some help with this. Perhaps I am using `:at` wrongly or you know what format `:at` in and help me convert `tomorrow`.

`start_onboarding` is just a AASM event, which calls this method to schedule email delivery (a bit modified for privacy reasons):

```
def notify(id)
  person = User.find(id) 
  PersonMailer.onboarding_reminder(person).
    deliver_later(wait_until: 1.day.from_now)
end
```

Comment: I doubt you want to sink in `Float` comparison, which basically has a lot of drawbacks. I would strongly advise to stick with what you currently have, since comparing `Date`s is way more robust for the test purposes, then comparing _milliseconds_. OTOH, `:at` parameter might be anything before `tomorrow`, so one might use `Date.tomorrow.noon` or like, as shown in [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html#method-i-assert_enqueued_with).

Comment: can you show me how `start_onboarding` enqueues the job please

Comment: @Anthony `start_onboarding` is just an event call from AASM gem, but I've added the method which actually schedules the mailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for the `wait_until` method needs to match what your test uses.  The date serialized into the queue does get turned into a float by [rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/102ee4055770813c847c95d3d6ff8741c33597d8/activejob/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb#L44).  And in your `#notify` method, you're passing in a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance when your test is passing in a `Date` instance.

See here:

```
1.day.from_now
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 13:56:36 UTC +00:00
1.day.from_now.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
1.day.from_now.to_date
=> Wed, 31 May 2017
1.day.from_now.to_date.class
=> Date
1.day.from_now == 1.day.from_now.to_date
=> false
```

That means your job is getting enqueued with time information but your test is expecting a simple date.  I'm not sure which is more correct the test date or the code date but they need to match for this test to pass.

Per the comments, here's how you might use [`Timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop#usage) to help you out:

```
  tomorrow = 1.day.from_now.to_date
  Timecop.freeze(tomorrow)
  assert_enqueued_with(job: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob, at: tomorrow) do
    onboarding.start_onboarding
  end
  Timecop.return
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. There are some inconsistencies left though. For some reason `:at` is 1 hour earlier than `tomorrow`. Not sure why timezones are different as `Job` has `+0100` and just adding an hour to `tomorrow` doesn't fix it due to timezone differences I assume...

Comment: Hm even if I get the times the same, it's still not equal...
`tomorrow.to_time == Time.at(job_date)`, both are of class `Time` and both are `2017-05-31 15:33:38 +0100`

Comment: Alright, it seems it's due to floats not being the same. I don't see the way to make them exactly the same and it just seems like a waste of time. Any idea how to not have such strict comparison?

Comment: Ya, likely that the test is run with one time and then a few milliseconds later the job is enqueued with another time.  You're better offer to use [`Timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop#usage) to stub time in your tests but at least you found your problem :)

Comment: How would you recommend using `Timecop`? I am not overly familiar with it

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 1):

The **at** option should be a Time.

See an example in the docs [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activejob/5.0.0/ActiveJob%2FTestHelper%3Aassert_enqueued_with)